# Display 'Hello World'  with a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Does somebody know of a way to display 'Hello World' in a blank page when a user of Firefox opens a new tab (with an extension) ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? The reference is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Reference

Comment: @BrunoLM I want to display text in the content area of a window with an extension and so far I've only found tutorials explaining how to modify the chrome (menus) with an extension.

Comment: I don't remember very well how to manipulate XULs, but try `window.getElementById("content_id").innerHTML = "something";`. When in XUL window refers to the current XUL.

Comment: @BrunoLM I don't understand : what does "content_id " refers to ?

Comment: You element. I understood the element you want to modify is in your XUL file. Using `gBrowser` instead of `window` you can modify other elements. Open `omni.jar` on Firefox folder and dig XUL files to see the IDs...

Comment: @BrunoLM Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I've changed my post consequently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this on your XUL file:

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function(e) {
        var contentWindow = e.originalTarget.defaultView;

        contentWindow//.getElementById, tagName, etc...

    }, false);
```

`contentWindow` is the wrapped `window` of that tab.

For the [raw window (Same window if you type a script on the address bar) see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845790/how-to-edit-a-property-on-window-from-firefox-addon/5849111#5849111).

Comment: As of Firefox 4 extensions aren't allowed to document.write directly into tabs. I don't know whether you can do it via e.g. sandboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your commitment BrunoLM ! I can't try your answer tonight but I'll give you the result tomorrow morning. :-)

Comment: I've tried to add my extension to Firefox and it says my file is corrupt and I don't understand why ! Can you please post your code or send it to me ?