# How to edit a property on `window` from Firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to make an addon that modifies one value on the `window`.

Let's take for example a simple window:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script>
            window.hello = 1;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Using

```
gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
    function (e)
    {
        e.originalTarget.defaultView.hello = 2;
    }, false);
```

does not modify the value of `window.hello`. Meaning `e.originalTarget.defaultView != window`.

How can I access the pure `window`?

Comment: I think `e.originalTarget` refers to the document of that page.  try `e.target.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.hello = 2`. I have similar code and that works for me.

Comment: @skabbes thanks it works! Post as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.originalTarget` refers to the document element of that page.  To access the window element of the page, you use `e.target.defaultView`.  However, in order to stay withing the bounds of Mozilla's security protocols, you must access the window object through its `wrappedJSObject` property.  Overall, you'd change the variable like:

```
e.target.defaultView.wrappedJSObject.hello = 2
```